# google play console ad section blank

Tags: google-app-maker

Im trying to finish the todos so I can rollout my app but the ad section is just blank
If I try to go to target audience it tells me to go back to ads
[heres the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NytGe.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off your ad blocker if you are using one.